# Who exactly committed suicide in the movie 'The Bounty Hunter'?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-bounty-hunter

In [The Bounty Hunter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bounty_Hunter_(2010_film)), Nicole Hunter mentions the suicide story so many times in the movie because she is a journalist and she wants to write an article on it.

But who exactly committed suicide in the movie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this scene in the movie Nicole calls Jimmy(The guy in the bar) from the bathroom of her office. The conversation is as follows.

> Jimmy -This is Jimmy.
>
> Nicole -Jimmy, Nicole from the Daily News.
>
> Jimmy -Nicole? Long time no talk. Where you been hiding yourself?
>
> Nicole -Right now I'm actually hiding in the bathroom at work. Listen, I need you to ask around about a suicide. **A Walter Lilly, Rivington Street...the night of June 23rd.**
>
> Jimmy -Twenty-three. Anything eIse?

From this scene we can be sure that Walter Lilly is the one who commits suicide.